# What type of expression is this in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

Considering x,p,r are evaluated from the previous expressions , what is happening underneath , <- and then after =

```
val a = for{
 x <- y
 p = q (x)
 r <- s (p)
} yield (something(p.something, r.something))
```

Answer (score 5):

The `<-` is equivalent (syntactic sugar) to `.flatMap` call, while `=` is equivalent to `val x =` (and `yield` kind of final `.map`).

So the code is equivalent to:

```scala
val a = y.flatMap { x => // first <-
  val p = q (x)
  s(p).map { r => // 2nd <- + yield
    something(p.something, r.something)
  }
}
```